# How to eliminate auto single quote added to formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

In the cell of a worksheet, I am trying to reference another cell on a different worksheet in the same workbook. Excel keeps putting a single quote in front of the equal sign in the formula square. I enter `=AllTeam!B2` in the cell and it changes it to `'=AllTeam!B2`.

What do I need to do to stop this?

Answer (score 12):

The single quote prefix means Excel is treating the cell as text.  Most likely, the cell is formatted as Text rather than General.  Select the cell, bring up the formatting on the cell, go to the `Number` tab, and under the `Category` list, select `General`.

You can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to get to the `Format Cells` dialog.  You don't say what version of Excel, but in modern versions of Excel, it is also available in the Ribbon, on the `Home` tab, in the `Number` section.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. If you consider your question resolved, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Or Cmd+1 for Macs. Also using `<kmd>` tags might look better than the [] you’ve used.

Comment: To my recollection CTRL/CMD+1 has been the formatting dialog shortcut in Excel forever.

Comment: That was in reference to the UI path for the mousey way to go it.

Comment: @BenScott I see. That makes sense but as written it seems you're saying the version *might* matter when it comes to the validity of that shortcut. Consider clarifying that a bit.